# Exponential/Logarithmic Trendlines in Google Chart

Tags: html, google-visualization, exponential, trendline

I am trying to set up a trendline chart that will eventually be sent data from Filemaker. But since this is the first time I am doing this, I am trying to just set one up with hard-coded data.

Ideally, I'd like the chart to have a curved trendline, like this (which was created in Excel) [Curved Trendline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7PJt.png), but when I set up the code using the HTML from the Google Charts site, the resulting chart has a straight line for the trendline, like this.[Straight Line Trendline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i71Ic.png)

Here is the code that I am using.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Period', 'Relativity'],
            [ 12,      0],
            [ 24,     0.25],
            [ 36,     0.35],
            [ 48,     0.37],
            [ 60,     0.52],
            [ 72,     null],
            [ 84,     null],
            [ 96,     null],            
            [ 108,    null],
            [ 120,    1]
        ]);

        var options = {
          hAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 1.5},
          chartArea: {width:'50%'},
          trendlines: {
            0: {
              type: 'Exponential',
              showR2: true,
              visibleInLegend: true
            }
          }
        };

        var chartExponential = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chartExponential'));
        chartExponential.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chartExponential" style="height: 350px; width: 800px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried switching the 'exponential' to logarithmic in the trendline definition (my term may be wrong!) but neither gives me the result I am looking for.

This is my first time stretching into this realm, so I am hoping it is something basic!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

TIA!

Comment: `type: 'exponential'` -- should be lower case, see [exponential trendlines](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines#exponential-trendlines)...

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Odd that something that simple solved it.